# Как из метода onClick передать переменную num в onOptionsItemSelected?

Tags: java, android

```
public class NewNote extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText edNewThemeNotes, edNewTextNotes;
ImageButton edLightRed, edLightYellow, edLightGreen, img_map;
ImageView edAddedPhoto;

DBHelper dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_note);

    edNewThemeNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edNewThemeNotes);
    edNewTextNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edNewTextNotes);

    edLightRed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edLightRed);
    edLightYellow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edLightYellow);
    edLightGreen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edLightGreen);

    edAddedPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edAddedPhoto);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);


}

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_note, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        int id = item.getItemId();

        String newTheme = edNewThemeNotes.getText().toString();
        String newText = edNewTextNotes.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.edAddNewNote:
                if (edNewThemeNotes.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast error = Toast.makeText(NewNote.this, R.string.toast_not_theme, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    error.show();
                }
                else if (edNewTextNotes.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast error = Toast.makeText(NewNote.this, R.string.toast_not_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    error.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_THEME, newTheme);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_TEXT, newText);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_PRIORITY, newNumPriority);

                    database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NOTES, null, contentValues);
                }
                break;
        }
    return false;
    }


    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    int id = view.getId();

    int num;

    if (id == R.id.edLightRed) {
        num = 1;
    }

    else if (id == R.id.edLightYellow){
        num = 2;
    }

    else if (id == R.id.edLightGreen){
        num = 3;
    }

    else {
        num = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно ничего никуда передавать, вы можете сделать переменную num членом класса NewNote, а не функции onCLick() (как dbHelper и др.), в функции onCLick() просто присваивать ей какое-либо значение, а в функции onOptionsItemSelected использовать эту переменную.

Объявляем:

```
EditText edNewThemeNotes, edNewTextNotes;
ImageButton edLightRed, edLightYellow, edLightGreen, img_map;
ImageView edAddedPhoto;

int num;

DBHelper dbHelper;
```

Присваиваем:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

int id = view.getId();

if (id == R.id.edLightRed) {
    num = 1;
}

else if (id == R.id.edLightYellow){
    num = 2;
}

else if (id == R.id.edLightGreen){
    num = 3;
}

else {
    num = 0;
}
}
```